# How can I access azure keyvault on different subscription when using Invoke-AzureTemplateDeployment

Tags: powershell, subscription, azure-keyvault

I have a keyvault set up on our Production "pay as you go" subscription with the certificates for the website i'm creating. I've written a powershell deployment script that creates the VM for the website.  When i launch the script locally it runs as my msdn azure subscription, and I get the following error when trying to deploy my template.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 8:56:34 AM - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines 'devSigmaMarketplaceUbuntuVM' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidParameter",
    "target": "sourceVault.id",
    "message": "The SubscriptionId:\"MY-PERSONAL-ID-b612-4402-b239-0c72253f2c84\" of the request must match the SubscriptionId \"THE-PRODUCTION-ID-4a56-4aa2-92ea-c02f6edf33b5\" 
contained in the Key Vault Id."
  }
```

}'

I understand the error.

The only solution I can come up with that works is to Select-AzureSubscription to the production ID, before I run New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment. This is not a practical solution, since then all of the VM will be deployed using those "financials" instead of the credits that come with my msdn.

Additional Info:

- The VM is running Linux 16.04 LTS
- The entire system is created using a combination of an azure deployment template, and bash commands